# Speeding up multinomial random sample in Python/NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, vectorization

I'm generating a vector of draws from a multinomial distribution over a set of probabilities `probs`, where each draw is the index of the entry in `probs` that was chosen:

```
import numpy as np
def sample_mult(K, probs):
    result = np.zeros(num_draws, dtype=np.int32)
    for n in xrange(K):
        draws = np.random.multinomial(1, probs)
        result[n] = np.where(draws == 1)[0][0]
    return result
```

Can this be sped up? It seems inefficient to call `np.random.multinomial` over and over again (and `np.where` might also be slow.)

`timeit` says `The slowest run took 6.72 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.9 µs per loop`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `size` option with [`np.random.multinomial`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.multinomial.html)  to have rows of random samples instead of just one row output with the default `size=1` and then use [`.argmax(1)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) to simulate [`np.where()[0][0]`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) behaviour.

Thus, we would have a vectorized solution, like so -

```
result = (np.random.multinomial(1,probs,size=K)==1).argmax(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The p= parameter to "choice" does this (and avoids the argmax):

```
result = np.random.choice(len(probs), K, p=probs)
```